# i try to upgrade my project in cakephp 3.8 to 4.0 but i stuck in this line "composer require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:4.0.*"

Tags: cakephp, upgrade, require, conflict

when i run "composer require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:4.0.*"
it responds :

./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update cakephp/cakephp --with-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires cakephp/cakephp 4.0.*, found cakephp/cakephp[4.0.0-alpha1, ..., 4.0.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
Problem 2
- cakephp/migrations is locked to version 1.5.7 and an update of this package was not requested.
- cakephp/migrations 1.5.7 requires cakephp/cakephp ~3.1 -> found cakephp/cakephp[3.1.0-beta, ..., 3.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (4.0.*).
Problem 3
- cakephp/debug_kit is locked to version 3.2.7 and an update of this package was not requested.
- cakephp/debug_kit 3.2.7 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.1.0 <4.0 -> found cakephp/cakephp[3.1.0-beta, ..., 3.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (4.0.*).
Problem 4
- cakephp/bake is locked to version 1.2.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
- cakephp/bake 1.2.3 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.2.0 -> found cakephp/cakephp[3.2.0-RC1, ..., 3.x-dev, 4.0.0-alpha1, ..., 4.x-dev, 5.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: did you follow the instructions? https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html

Comment: I would at least try to follow the suggestion `Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W)` which differs from `--update-with-dependencies`; `composer help require` tells you the difference.

Comment: tq @salines i do follow the upgrade guide, and already try the --update-with-dependencies this option too...@code-kobold, but result are the same